# VirtualBox VPN messed up my hosts network connection

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, vpn

I'm running Kubuntu 19.10 as my host and Windows 10 as a guest in a VM.

My work asked me to install a VPN package on Windows to access the internal network, however since doing so the internet access on my host machine doesn't work anymore.

How can I fix or troubleshoot this? I tried the usual things like resetting the wifi and rebooting but I don't know much about other steps

Comment: Troubleshooting step: Try a wired connection and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Also details on how you set up networking in the VM might help.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'll try wired when I get back home, but it seems to sporadically work again over wifi. @Kurankat, it's just the basic network setup (no changes) so I suppose it was set to NAT, however I changed it to Bridged after reading a few other comments

Comment: If you're using default NAT, I struggle to see how changes to the guest's network might affect the host (I also presume you're not passing whole devices to the guest). Sorry I can't offer any more useful ideas!